$L^1$ Convergence implies convergence of negative and positive components
For a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ fulfilling $X_n \overset{L^1}{\to} X$, it holds per definition that $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X |] \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} 0$. Moreover, we get from $ |\mathbb{E}\mathbb[X_n - X] | \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X |]$ that $\mathbb{E}[X_n] \overset{n \to \infty}{\to} \mathbb{E}[X] $.
If we express $X_n$ and $X$ as the difference of their positive and negative components, i.e. $X_n = X_n^+ - X_n^-$ and $X = X^+ - X^-$, does it necessarily mean that $X_n^+ \overset{L^1}{\to} X^+$ and $X_n^- \overset{L^1}{\to} X^-$?

We have $||X_n|-|X||\leq |X_n-X|$, i.e. $\mathbb{E}[||X_n| - |X||] \leq \mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|].$ Since $\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|] \to 0$, it follows that $\mathbb{E}[||X_n| - |X||] \to 0,$ which implies $|X_n|\to |X|$ in $L^1$.
You may write $$X_n^+ = \frac{|X_n| + X_n}{2} \, \text{ and }  \, X_n^- = \frac{|X_n| - X_n}{2}$$ Consider:$$|X_n^+ - X^+| = \left|\frac{|X_n| +X_n}{2} - \frac{|X| + X}{2}\right|\leq \frac{|X_n - X| + ||X_n| - |X||}{2}.
$$ Thus, $$\mathbb{E}[|X_n^+ - X^+|] \leq \frac{\mathbb{E}[|X_n - X|] + \mathbb{E}[||X_n| - |X||]}{2}\to 0.$$ $X_n^{-}$ is analogous.
